# Simple Ito Formula Application to Stochastic Integration

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following definitions from my course,

#### Ito Process

Given an $\mathbb{F}$-Wiener Martingale $W$, we say that a process $X=\{X_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ is an Ito process if there exists an $\mathcal{F}_0$ measurable random variable $S$ and processes $g$ and $f$ such that,

$$X_t = S + \int_0^t g_s ds + \int_0^t f_s dW_s.$$

#### Ito's Formula

We have $X:[0,T] \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ an Ito process with stochastic differential $dX_t = g_t dt + f_t dW_t$ and let  $u \in C^2$. Then $Y_t = u(t,X_t)$ is also an Ito process with stochastic differential given by Ito's Formula,

$$dY_t = (\partial_t u(t,X_t) + \partial_x u(t,X_t)g_t + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{xx}^2 u(t,X_t) f_t)dt + \partial_x u(t,X_t) f_t dW_t$$

---

I understand this is very basic, however, I am lacking in understanding. My question is surrounding the application of Ito's formula to examples, even in their most basic form. Consider that I am trying to model the process $X_t = W_t^2$ by Ito's formula. I let $u(t,x)=x^2$ and calculate the partial derivatives, which are of course, $\partial_x u(t,x) = 2x, \partial_{xx} u(t,x) = 2$ and $\partial_t u(t,x) = 0$. When we substitute these partial derivates into Ito's formula, we get

$$dX_t = (2x g_t + f_t)dt + 2x f_t dW_t$$
$$dX_t = (2W_t g_t + f_t)dt + 2W_t f_t dW_t$$

However, the given answer for this question is $dX_t = dt + 2W_t dW_t$. My questions are:

1. Why do the functions $f_t$ and $g_s$ disappear from Ito's formula? It looks like we are setting $f_t = 1$ and $g_t=0$, why is this?
2. Why do we make this "change of variables" from $x$ to $W_t$?

Comment: The process $W_t$ itself has $g_t=0,f_t=1$, that is the SDE that it corresponds to. And there is no change of variable really, the point is that $Y_t$ is represented as a function of $t$ and some other process $X_t$, and in this case $X_t$ is $W_t$. The letter $x$ is just introduced as a name for the second argument of $u$. In the form above as you saw, you ultimately replace $x$ with $X_t$, that is what those function evaluations mean.

Comment: Okay, I see. When will it be the case that $g_t \neq 0$ and $f_t\neq1$?

Comment: Just depends what you want to represent your process as a transformation of. It is often convenient to represent it as a transformation of standard Brownian motion but not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to model a function of $W_t$. So to apply Ito you should consider the Ito process
$$dX_t=\mu(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$$
where $\mu(t,X_t)=0$ and $\sigma(t,X_t)=1$, obtaining $dX_t=dW_t$. If $F(X_t)=X^2_t$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=0,\, \frac{\partial F}{\partial w}=2w, \, \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial w^2}=2$$
Thus, by Ito
$$dF=\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}dX_t+\frac{1}{2}\sigma(X_t,t)^2\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial w^2}dt=2W_tdW_t+dt$$